# Move a array of pictures path/name in a folder with php

Tags: php

I have a folder called images (on server side), and there will be added pictures, constantly, I want a function that will move all the pictures from that folder (images) on another folder (called with the number of actual month) that is inside the images folder. So I will basically have a folder images with other folders each one having the month number, so lets say for today the folder 03 (March).

This is the function so far:

```
public function createCurrentMonthFolder() {
        $month = date("m");
        $directory = "./images/".$month;
        if(!is_dir($directory)){
            mkdir($directory, 775, true);
            }
        $source= "./images";
        $images = glob('./images/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
        $dest = "./images/".$month;
        var_dump($images);
        copy($source, $dest);
        unlink($source);
    }
```

So the first part will check if the folder of the current month is there already( if not create it). In the $images variable I will get the array of the image names like this :

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "./images/14.jpg" [1]=> string(17) "./images/ji.jpg" }
```

And I want to move all that images in the $dest, that will actually be the current month folder name.

Problem is that copy() accepts only a file not a array that I send and also unlink() will want to get a file not a dir.

So how can I move the array of pictures into my desired folder and delete them after from the images folder? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can make a loop to access array,

```
foreach($images as $image){
 copy($image, $dest);
 unlink($image);
}
```

Comment: I will got this warning: Message: copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory and after that the image will be deleted. is seems that $dest var cannot be a dir.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this may help you:

```
    $all_files = scandir('/home/user/Desktop/images');

    $source = '/home/user/Desktop/images/' ;
    $destination = '/home/user/Desktop/images/03/';

    foreach($all_files as $files){
        if(is_file($source.$files)){
            rename($source.$files,$destination.$files);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't get how the rename thing will help? Is something that I miss ? I already defined the paths from where and where I want to move the images in my variables.

Comment: You might be define the path till folder. Don't only specify path till folder. Specify the path till file name in source and destination both as i given example above.

Comment: Thing is that as I stated above, I will get lots of images there, random names, random number of them and I want to organize them in months, I won't have to know for each one who will be his name.

Comment: Hi Tatu, You can refer edited example. This might be help you.